# UI loop errors, can't get UI options to keep going or stopping

Tags: java, arrays, loops, user-interface

So I have this program that builds a School using dynamic arrays instead of using Array List. I have the methods created and tested, everything works except I'm trying to get the UI to work.

The UI is supposed to take user input to build the array of Students. Normal students versus CS students. The problem is, when I enter in how many students I want to enter into the school either regular or CS students, it stops after I enter in the amount of students I request to enroll.

I want the ability to say enroll 5 students, then go back and be asked if I want to enroll more, drop a student, or do any of the other options listed on the main menu. That's my problem. Every time I try to add in a for loop or switch the if/else if statements around compilation errors abound. This is the entire code that I have created:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class School {
private Student[] theStudents;

public School() {
    this.theStudents = new Student[0];// needs to start out as empty
}

/*
 * next two methods would allow a user to add or drop a student into the
 * student array for the school ??Also with Enroll student, should be able
 * to assign a class to the student, i.e. Calculas, history, etc??
 */
public void enrollStudent(Student newStudent) {
    Student totalStudents[] = new Student[theStudents.length + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < theStudents.length; i++) {
        totalStudents[i] = theStudents[i];
    }
    totalStudents[theStudents.length] = newStudent;
    theStudents = totalStudents;
}

public void dropStudent(String dropStudent) {
    boolean checkForName = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < theStudents.length; i++) {
        if (theStudents[i].getName().equals(dropStudent)) {
            theStudents[i] = null;
            checkForName = true;
        }
    }
    if (checkForName == true) {
        Student totalStudents[] = new Student[theStudents.length - 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < totalStudents.length; i++) {
            if (theStudents[i] == null) {
                totalStudents[i] = theStudents[theStudents.length - 1];
            } else {
                totalStudents[i] = theStudents[i];
            }
        }
        theStudents = totalStudents;
    }
    if (checkForName == false) {
        System.out.println("The Student does not exist in the school");
    }
}

// add Test Score for a student
public void addTestScore(String newStudent, double testScore) {
    for (int i = 0; i < theStudents.length; i++) {
        if (newStudent.equals(theStudents[i])) {
            theStudents[i].addTestScore(testScore);
        }
    }
}

/*
 * count the number of students in a given class, not the school
 */
public int countClassSize(String course) {
    // Need to access how the course names are stored for the school to
    // count this size.
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < theStudents.length; i++) {
        if (theStudents[i].getClassName().equals(course)) {
            count = count + 1;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

/*
 * get average average score of the student array The student array is made
 * up of Regular students and CompSciStudents. The average should take the
 * average of both the average score for Students and average score of
 * CompSciStudents and return the average average.
 */
public double averageAverageScore(String course) {
    double avgAvgTest = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < theStudents.length; i++) {
        if (theStudents[i].getClassName().equals(course)) {
            avgAvgTest += theStudents[i].getTestAvg();
        }
    }
    return avgAvgTest / this.countClassSize(course);
}

/*
 * add a programming language to only CS students at the school Will need to
 * use the instanceof for proper type casting
 */
public void addProgrammingLanguage(String studentName, String programLanguage) {
    for (int i = 0; i < theStudents.length; i++) {
        if (this.theStudents[i] instanceof CompSciStudent) {
            CompSciStudent tempStudent = (CompSciStudent) this.theStudents[i];
            tempStudent.learnedLanguage(programLanguage);
        }
    }
}

/*
 * Count the number of students in the school that know a certain
 * programming language, again will need to typecast properly
 */
public int numberThatKnowLanguage(String programLanguage) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < theStudents.length; i++) {
        if (this.theStudents[i] instanceof CompSciStudent) {
            CompSciStudent tempStudent = (CompSciStudent) this.theStudents[i];
            String knowThisLanguage = programLanguage;
            tempStudent.learnedLanguage(knowThisLanguage);
            count += 1;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String dropStudent, course;

    System.out.println("Welcome to the School. Please select\n" + " Option 1 to enroll a regular student,"
            + "Option 2 to enroll a CompSci student, \n" + "Option 3 to drop a student, \n"
            + "Option 4 to add test score or programming language, or \n" + "Option 5 to perform class analytics.");
    int Operation = input.nextInt();

    /*
     * Simple UI to add and drop students, will need to set the operation to
     * call the add and drop students to fit them to the Student body array
     * will need to make these two options loop until the user is satisfied
     * with the size of the student body
     */
    if (Operation == 1) {
        System.out.println("Enter the # of regular students that you want to add to the school.");
        int addStudents = input.nextInt();
        // Possibly create some type of input array to
        // make it easier to enter the students' names. for(<type> <var
        // name> : <array name>)
        System.out.println("Please enter the name and course of the student you are enrolling:");
        for (int i = 0; i < addStudents; i++) {
            String newRegularStudent = (String) input.next();
            course = input.next();
            System.out.println("Enter next student's name and then the course's name that he is enrolling in.");

        }
    } else if (Operation == 2) {
        System.out.println("Enter the # of CompSci students that you want to add to the school.");
        int addStudents = input.nextInt();
        /*
         * Possibly create some type of input array to make it easier to
         * enter the students' names
         */
        System.out.println("Please enter the name and course of the student you are enrolling:");
        String newCompSciStudent = (String) input.next();
        course = input.next();
    }

    else if (Operation == 3) {
        System.out.println("Enter the # of students that you want to drop from the school.");
        int dropStudents = input.nextInt();
        /*
         * Possibly create some type of input array to make it easier to
         * enter the students' names
         */
        System.out.println("Please enter the name of the student you wish to drop from the school:");
        dropStudent = (String) input.next();

        /*
         * After the first two operations, will need to build to the UI to
         * call the other five methods, will need to make it into a
         * while/for loop so user can continue to add information as needed.
         */
    }

    else if (Operation == 4) {
        System.out.println("Enter the # for what you want to add to a student's records."
                + "Enter 1 to enter a test score\n " + "Enter 2 to enter a programming language, enter 2.");
        int optionNum1 = input.nextInt();
        /*
         * Possibly create some type of input array to make it easier to
         * enter the students' names
         */
        if (optionNum1 == 1) {

        } else if (optionNum1 == 2) {

        }
    }

    else if (Operation == 5) {
        System.out.println("This is the analytics section of this program.\n");

        System.out.println("Enter the # for which of the following analytics options that you want performed: "
                + "Enter 1 to count the # of students for a particular class,\n "
                + "Enter 2 to calculate the average average score for all students take a particular course, or\n "
                + "Enter 3 to count the # of CompSciStudents.");
        int optionNum2 = input.nextInt();
        if (optionNum2 == 1) {
            System.out.println("Enter the course name that you\n" + " want to know the # of students for.");
            course = input.next();
            Student classSize;
        }

        else if (optionNum2 == 2) {
            System.out.println(
                    "Enter the course name that you want to \n" + "calculate the average average test value for.");
            course = input.next();
            Student testAvg;
        }

        else if (optionNum2 == 3) {
            System.out.println("Count the # of CompSciStudents who know a particular programming\n"
                    + " language by entering that language name now.");
            String programLanguage = input.next();
            CompSciStudent csStudent = null;
            csStudent.knowsLanguage(programLanguage);
        }
    }
    input.close();

}
}
```

Comment: you *cannot* give size to an array in run time. so size will always  stay as 0. use something else like ArrayList.

Comment: @kaanyılmaz That should be an answer. Anyways, kaan is totally right. In fact, `ArrayList` is the Java way of creating _Dynamic Arrays_! And even though you said you don't want to use `ArrayList`, there is no other possibility unless you code a new `DynamicArray` class. However that means you have to drop Java's pretty Array-Syntax and will worsen your runtime-performance.

Comment: @Krazor I'm adding it as an answer then.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the size of an array in Java at runtime. The size of your array therefore will always be zero since you wrote:

```
this.theStudents = new Student[0];
```

I would suggest you to use:

```
ArrayLists<type> list = new ArrayLists<type>();
```

If you do now know how to use ArrayLists you can follow this [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_arraylist_class.htm).